# Camera analysis only entering to analyze method in ImageAnalysis.Analyzer only once, in Xiaomi Mi a20 Lite

Tags: android, android-camerax, xiaomi

The analysis works fine in every other Android phone I've tried (Huawei Mate 20 Pro, Samsung S8, Samsung J7 and Samsung S10+), but not in the Xiaomi Mi a20 Lite. It only enters once the the `analyze` function and then in the Logcat throws:

```
E/ImageAnalysisAnalyzer: Failed to acquire image.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (1) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.
```

I've built the analyser like this, because we want it to bring a new frame only when the one in the queue has been processed:

```
val imageAnalysis = builder
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_BLOCK_PRODUCER)
                    .setImageQueueDepth(1)
                    .build()
```

In the `analyze` function we make sure to close the `image`, but the error comes up nonetheless in this particular Xiaomi device:

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
            val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)
            scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes: List<Barcode?> ->
                        if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                            EventBus.getDefault().post(OnRetrievedSuccess(barcodes))
                        }
                        image.mediaImage?.close()
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(OnRetrievedFailure())
                        image.mediaImage?.close()
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the blocking mode, you probably can try to use at least 2 buffers and see if that works?  When you are using non-blocking mode with STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST,  setImageQueueDepth() is not used by CameraX.

Comment: image.mediaImage?.close() can not be used.  just imageProxy?.close() is enough: it will free the wrapped MediaImage.  refer to https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved changing the image strategy when building:

```
val imageAnalysis = builder
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .setImageQueueDepth(1)
                    .build()
```

Seemed more reasonable to process one frame and then ask another, but with this strategy it worked fine in every phone.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Builder#setImageQueueDepth(int)

The value only applies to ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_BLOCK_PRODUCER mode. For ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST the value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`image.mediaImage?.close()` can not be used. just `imageProxy?.close()` is enough: it will free the wrapped `MediaImage`. refer to `developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze` –
Gerry
Nov 19 at 1:01